# How can I see when a cell had its contents cleared vs. set to 0 in a "Worksheet_Change" sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code in a "Worksheet_Change" sub where i need to store potential changes in values of cells (always integer). However, when a value is deleted, it appears as "0" in my worksheet, and I need it to show no value at all, since "0" and "nothing" is handled in completely different ways in my file.

So, how can I code so that I can tell the difference between what is being set as zero, and what is being deleted in order to, when I need to delete the value of a cell (so clear its contents), it will appear empty instead of with a zero?

I believe the problem can be somewhere in the following part:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim oldQty As Integer
Dim newQty As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
With Target
    newQty = .Value
    Application.Undo
    oldQty = .Value
    .Value = newQty
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
    
(...)

End Sub
```

I need this to store the old quantity of the cell.
I hope I was clear enough, any help is appreciated

Comment: `Target.Value` returns either `0` (if it has the value zero) or `""` (if it has no value) then. If that does not answer the question please read [mcve] and provide a full example with some code and error description so it is reproducible. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). • Also check the [IsEmpty function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function)

Comment: It's just that if i clear the contents of a cell (press "delete"), it assumes its value is zero, hence showing a zero in that cell. I just wanted a way to avoid this and make it show as empty...

Comment: That is no default behavior of Excel. If you press delete the default behaviour is that the cell is empty. So you must have changed something.

Comment: I edited my post with the part of the code where I believe the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line at the very beginning of `Worksheet_Change`.

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'prevent error in case of range edits
```

And change the following part

```
With Target
    newQty = .Value
    Application.Undo
    oldQty = .Value
    .Value = IIf(newQty = 0, vbNullString, newQty)
      'if value is zero return an epmty string instead of `0`
End With
```

Comment: The problem is that I still need to store the new value, even if it's empty... should i dim oldQty and newQty as variants and then excel will be able to store them as either "" or number? Edit: Doing it this way seems to work, I'll keep it for now...